# How to enable yank-nth-arg using vi mode on Bash?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, vi-mode

Hey guys I'm trying to figure out how can I take my nth arg, from my last command, without using the !:nth. In a normal bash (emacs mode) I can do that using the follow shortcuts:

```
<ESC>nth_arg <ESC><c-y>
```

how can I do the same using the bash vi mode (bash -o vi) ?

my relevant .bashrc lines

```
set -o vi
#BASH yank-nth-arg: <esc>narg <c-a>y
#BASH yank-last-arg: <a-.>
bind -m vi-insert '"\e.": yank-last-arg'
```

my current binds with yank in it:

```
$ bind -lp | grep 'yank'
vi-yank-arg
vi-yank-to
yank
yank-last-arg
yank-nth-arg
yank-pop
# vi-yank-arg (not bound)
# vi-yank-to (not bound)
"\C-y": yank
"\e.": yank-last-arg
# yank-nth-arg (not bound)
# yank-pop (not bound)
```

currently when I try to do the:

```
<ESC>1 <ESC><c-y> or <ESC>1 <ALT-c-y>
```

I get a space/tab, or nothing happens after the (arg: 1) prompt disappears.

BR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use below bind key:

```
bind -m vi-insert '".": yank-last-arg'
```

or:

```
bind -m vi-insert ".":insert-last-argument
```

To get the nth arguments:

```
bind -m vi-command '"\e-": yank-nth-arg'
```

Now you can use `<ALT>n <ALT>-` to get nth argument from previous command.

Comment: I think you got me wrong. In my "~/.bashrc" I already have this line (bind -m vi-insert '"\e.": yank-last-arg') and my shortcut to get the last argument works "<ALT>.". What I'm asking is to retrieve my nth argument from the last command.

Comment: @MaikoID: See my updated answer.

Comment: thx, with ALT doesn't work but with ESC does. So it's good for me.

Comment: I don’t think anybody wants to remap `.` in insert mode, add `\e` before the dot as done by OP.